A children’s chapter book of a boy becoming a wizard’s apprentice and learning to shapeshift into a red fox
It could be published in the early 2000’s, and is probably in a similar age range to the early-mid Harry Potter novels. I think it may possibly have been set in a town along the coast (I keep thinking the coast of Maine, but I don’t know how accurate that is). The wizard can shapeshift into a gray fox. The boy is probably around 13 years old.

Might it be The Magician's House as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/what-was-this-book-time-travelling-kids-an-old-house-a-wizard-turning-into-a?

Red fox or gray fox? Which is it?

Not The Magician's House (unless the OP has mis-remembered the story). In that series William does not turn into a fox. The fox is just a fox (called Cinnabar) but William can travel with it in the sense of experiencing what it experiences.
